# Chrome app - setBounds() deprecated

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

now that [setBounds is deprecated](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#type-AppWindow) , how can I replace this code :

```
chrome.app.window.current().setBounds({width: aaa});
```

it says "Use innerBounds or outerBounds."... how?
for every syntax I try, error is (object/number is not a function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and I found the solution by looking at one of the samle apps called WindowState, you can find it here:

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples

To set the position of the window, you can do the following:

chrome.app.window.current().outerBounds.setPosition(positionLeft,positionTop);

Being positionLeft and positionTop the corresponding pixels.

What i wanted to do is positioning the app window to the center of the screen, so I did this

chrome.app.window.current().outerBounds.setPosition(Math.round(window.screen.availWidth*0.5-170),100);

You can see that the argument for the leftPosition is this:

Math.round(window.screen.availWidth*0.5-170)

It will get the user's screen width and set the position to 0.5 of the available width minus the half of the window size. In my case the window size is 340 that's why i used 170. The math round will prevent to get an invalid value, because the position should be in units.

The top position is just 100px.

Hope this helps.